# Not able to target and shoot in Red dead redemption when controls are changed

Tags: controllers, red-dead-redemption

I am used to target and shoot with L1 and R1 respectively. By default, in RDR target and shoot are L2 and R2 respectively. There is an option called "flip R1 with R2 and L1 with L2" in setings->Options->Config and I have selected 'inverted' in that option and saved it. After that I am able to select between different weapons but not able to target and shoot with L1 and R1. There is no action for those two buttons and I have to restart the game again to target and shoot once this happens.

I have updated the game every time it has asked me to. I am playing in hardcore mode and platform is PS3. Please someone let me know what is the problem. Any help is appreciated.